# How do I align my object with the ground?

Tags: objects, transforms, snapping

I'm new to Blender and created a gas stove knob model (to replace an old one that came off)  to 3D print, but my model is not aligned with the ground. I think the rotation is slightly off, as well. When I searched it up on YouTube and Google, all I found were answers from 5+ years ago, and most of the answers on this website use words that I'm not familiar with. Could somebody please explain to me how to align my model with the ground (both rotation and transformation)? And to describe modes or specific buttons, it would be helpful if you mentioned exactly where on the screen (default screen layout, Blender v3.[image]6) they are.

Thank you! And sorry for not knowing a thing about where all the buttons are located

Comment: Maybe in Object mode try Alt R and Alt G?

Comment: If you press 1 (front view) or 3 (side view) on the numpad, that will show you how your object is aligned in the view. You can also click the vertical 'Item' tab to the right of the 3D window which will show you the rotation of the object.

Comment: If you press 'Shift+S->To origin' you will place the cursor in the center of the workspace. Then you can select the object in object mode or the geometry in edit mode and click 'Shift+S->To Cursor (Offset)'. This will move it to the cursor. You don't need to do this stuff when exporting an STL tho, afaik the format doesn't save location information like that. When you open it in the slicer program it will center it in the 3D object, not on where the origin was before